# How to limit the number of user requests made within a minute

Tags: php, url, ip, limit

A user will request a file by number via a URL like `script.php?userid=222`. This example would show the record of file #222.

Now I want to limit the number of files per (remote IP) user to a maximum of 5 different records in a minute. However, the user should be able to access the same id record any number of time.

So the user could access file #222 any number of times, but if the (remote IP) user accesses more than 5 other different records in a minute, then it should show an error.

For example, suppose within a minute the following requests are made:

```
script.php?userid=222
script.php?userid=523
script.php?userid=665
script.php?userid=852
script.php?userid=132
script.php?userid=002
```

then at the last request it should show the error message.

Here is the basic code:

```
$id = $_GET['userid'];
if (!isset($_GET['userid']) || empty($_GET['userid'])) {
    echo "Please enter the userid";
    die();
}

if (file_exists($userid.".txt") &&
        (filemtime($userid.".txt") > (time() - 3600 * $ttime ))) {
    $ffile = file_get_contents($userid.".txt");} else {
    $dcurl = curl_init();
    $ffile = fopen($userid.".txt", "w+");
    curl_setopt($dcurl, CURLOPT_URL,"http://remoteserver.com/data/$userid");
    curl_setopt($dcurl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($dcurl, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_0);
    curl_setopt($dcurl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 50);
    curl_setopt($dcurl, CURLOPT_FILE, $ffile);
    $ffile = curl_exec($dcurl); 
    if(curl_errno($dcurl)) // check for execution errors
    {
        echo 'Script error: ' . curl_error($dcurl);
        exit;
    }
    curl_close($dcurl);
    $ffile = file_get_contents($userid.".txt");
}
```

Comment: The most reliable way would be to save the ip address somewhere (like a file or database) together with the file id's accessed and a datetime field. But that'll generate quite some server traffic and a heavy load on a mysql server if you have a lot of users. A cookie or session with a timeout will take a lot less resources. But they're also quite easy to circumvent. (delete cookies or close browser to destroy session). I guess you'll have to choose between reliability and scalability first.

Comment: I'm saying *most reliable* here because these days you can't really rely on an IP address. Browsers like *Tor* can give you a new IP address within 5 seconds by simply pushing a button. So I'd probebly ask myself if it's really worth the trouble first?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Instead of relying on the IP address, you could use the session mechanism. You can create a session scope via `session_start()`, and then store information that sticks with the same user session.

I would then suggest to keep in this session scope the list of unique IDs used in previous requests that user made, together with the time of the request, ignoring any repeated requests, which are always allowed. As soon as this list contains 5 elements with a time stamp within the last minute and a new ID is requested, you show the error and refuse the lookup.

Here is the code that does this. You should place it right after you have checked the presence of the *userid* argument, and before the retrieval of the file contents:

```
// set the variables that define the limits:
$min_time = 60; // seconds
$max_requests = 5;

// Make sure we have a session scope
session_start();

// Create our requests array in session scope if it does not yet exist
if (!isset($_SESSION['requests'])) {
    $_SESSION['requests'] = [];
}

// Create a shortcut variable for this array (just for shorter & faster code)
$requests = &$_SESSION['requests'];

$countRecent = 0;
$repeat = false;
foreach($requests as $request) {
    // See if the current request was made before
    if ($request["userid"] == $id) {
        $repeat = true;
    }
    // Count (only) new requests made in last minute
    if ($request["time"] >= time() - $min_time) {
        $countRecent++;
    }
}

// Only if this is a new request...
if (!$repeat) {
    // Check if limit is crossed.
    // NB: Refused requests are not added to the log.
    if ($countRecent >= $max_requests) {
        die("Too many new ID requests in a short time");
    }   
    // Add current request to the log.
    $countRecent++;
    $requests[] = ["time" => time(), "userid" => $id];
}

// Debugging code, can be removed later:
echo  count($requests) . " unique ID requests, of which $countRecent in last minute.<br>"; 

// if execution gets here, then proceed with file content lookup as you have it.
```

#### Deleted session cookies...

Sessions are maintained by cookies on the client. The user may delete such cookies, an so get a new session, which would allow the user to make new requests without regard of what was previously requested.

One way to get around this is to introduce a cool-down period for each new session. For instance, you could have them wait for 10 seconds before a first request can be made. To do that, replace in above code:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['requests'])) {
    $_SESSION['requests'] = [];
}
```

By:

```
$initial_delay = 10; // 10 seconds delay for new sessions
if (!isset($_SESSION['requests'])) {
    $_SESSION['requests'] = array_fill(0, $max_requests,
        ["userid" => 0, "time" => time()-$min_time+$initial_delay] 
    );
}
```

This is of course less user friendly as it affects any new session, also of users who are not trying to cheat by deleting cookies.

#### Registration

The better way is to only allow the lookup services to registered users. For this you must provide a user database and authentication system (for example password based). The requests should be logged in the database, keyed by the user's ID. If then a new session starts, the user must first authenticate again, and once authenticated the request history is retrieved from the database. This way the user cannot cheat around it by changing something on their client configuration (IP address, cookies, employing multiple devices in parallel, ...)

Comment: Thanks very much, it works like a charm, Amazing! You are master, You solve my problem! Happy New Year and Merry Christmas in Advance.

Comment: Sessions are identified by cookies. If someone deletes the cookie, or doesn't store it then he can send unlimited number of requests.

Comment: @BojanHrnkas, absolutely! I added a paragraph on this subject and an advice to require authentication.

Comment: @trincot what about protecting the registration itself? For UX I'd like to log the user in directly after the registration but that gives feedback if the user exists or not.

Comment: That might be something to ask. Go ahead and post a question.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php 
// session_start();
// session_destroy();
// exit;
echo index();
function index()
{
    $id = rand(000,020);
    $min_time = 60;
    $max_requests = 5;
    // $id = 0;
    session_start();
    $repeat = false;
    
    if(!isset($_SESSION["countRecent"]) && !isset($_SESSION["countRecent"]) && !isset($_SESSION["countRecent"])){
        $_SESSION["countRecent"] = 1;
        $_SESSION["time"] = time();
        $_SESSION['userid'][] = $id;
    }else{
        if ($_SESSION["countRecent"] >= $max_requests) {
            if(!in_array($id,$_SESSION['userid'])){
                if ($_SESSION["time"] <= time() - $min_time) {
                    $_SESSION["countRecent"] = 1;
                    $_SESSION["time"] = time();
                }else{
                    return("Too many requests in a short time wait ". ( $_SESSION["time"] - (time() - $min_time)  )). " Seconds";
                }
            }
        }else{
            if(!in_array($id,$_SESSION['userid'])){
                $_SESSION["countRecent"] = $_SESSION["countRecent"] + 1;
                $_SESSION['userid'][] = $id;
            }
        }
    }
    return "Your Result goes here.. id: $id  Counts: ". $_SESSION["countRecent"];
}
```

Try this. **Fast** , **low memory usage**

But not secure;

also use **database**

```
<?php 
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "","db_name") or die("Could not connect database");
$id = rand(0,99);
// $id = 100;
echo index($id);
function index($id,$user=1,$ip='192.168.0.10',$max_requests = 5,$min_time = 20)
{
    global $conn;
    $time = time();
    $req = "INSERT INTO `limit_api_by_ip2`(`id`, `ip`, `time`, `user`, `req`) 
    VALUES (null,INET_ATON('$ip'),'$time','$user',1)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE req=req+1;";
    
    $req2 = "INSERT INTO `limit_api_by_ip2`(`id`, `ip`, `time`, `user`, `req`) 
    VALUES (null,INET_ATON('$ip'),'$time','$user',1)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE req=1,`time`='".time()."' ;";
    
    $reqid = "INSERT INTO `limit_api_by_ip2_count`(`id`, `user`, `ids`) VALUES (null,'$user',$id)";
    
    $getid = "SELECT `ids` FROM `limit_api_by_ip2_count` WHERE user = $user and ids = $id limit 1;";
    
    $gettime = "SELECT `time`,`req` FROM `limit_api_by_ip2` WHERE user = $user and ip = INET_ATON('$ip') limit 1;";
    // $id = 0;
    $q = mysqli_query($conn,$getid);
    $c = mysqli_num_rows($q);
    if($c==0){
        $get_time = mysqli_query($conn,$gettime);
        $c1 = mysqli_num_rows($get_time);
        if($c1==0){
            mysqli_query($conn,$req);
            mysqli_query($conn,$reqid);
        }else{
            $row = mysqli_fetch_row($get_time);
            
            if ($row[1] >= $max_requests) {
                if ($row[0] <= (time() - $min_time)) {
                    mysqli_query($conn,$req2);
                    mysqli_query($conn,$reqid);
                }else{
                    return "Too many requests in a short time wait ".($row[0]-(time() - $min_time))." Seconds";
                }
            }else{
                mysqli_query($conn,$req);
                mysqli_query($conn,$reqid);
            }
        }

    }else{
        
    }
    if(isset($row[1]))
    {
        $cc = "Counts: ".$row[1];
        $dd = "new id: $id";
    }else{
        $cc = '';
        $dd = "old id: $id";
    }
    return "Your Result goes here.. $dd  ".$cc; 
}
```