# Is this script really useful to prevent attacks on a public php script which uploads an image?

Tags: php, security, ddos

extending this answer [How to limit the number of user requests made within a minute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34475376/how-t)… I developed this script. It responds true or false, depending if within 15 minutes one has called a script (in my case a simple PHP upload script, which includes the below script) more than 10 times.
It does work indeed, but I'd like to know if it is really useful in avoiding attacks such as DDOS or anything similar. In other words, does this add a security layer to a public PHP script? Does anyone know how could I improve it? The thing is, the script called to upload images has to be public in my case.

I hope that this script may be useful to someone too.

```
 <?
function isAllowed() {
$ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']?$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']:($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDE‌​D_FOR']?$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']:$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

if (file_exists($ip.".txt")) {
    $myfile = fopen($ip.".txt", "a");
    $txt = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    fwrite($myfile, $txt . "\n");

    $subject = file_get_contents($ip.".txt");

    $separator = "\n";
    $line = strtok($subject, $separator);

    $count = 0;

    while ($line !== false) {
        $line = strtok( $separator );
        $currentTime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $before15mins = strtotime('-15 minutes');
        $before15minsAsDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $before15mins);
        $time = strtotime( $line );
        $myDate = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $time );        

        if ($before15minsAsDate > $myDate) { 
        }
        else {
            $count++;
        }
    }

    if($count > 10) {
        //echo("too many attempts: " . $count);
        return false;
    }
    else {
        //echo("counting: " . $count);
        return true;
    }

} else {

    fopen($ip.".txt","w");
    return true;
}
}
?>
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a question.

Comment: But I see question marks. However, not only it is a question but it gives an extension to a up voted answer which I cite.