# Populate Latitude and Longitude in the database from the user's IP

Tags: php, mysql, geolocation

I have a "users" table with columns:

```
Id | user_id | name | ip_address | lat | lng
```

The id column, user_id, name and ip_address have been populated, and now have 100k users.
The lat (latitude) and lng (longitude) columns have now been created, and I need them populated from the IP (you can not get the geolocation of the user).
I do not want precise location, just the approximate location, so what I need is a script that picks up the IP of each user, somehow extracts the latitude and longitude, and inserts into the database.

I have looked at "http://www.geoplugin.net/xml.gp?ip=" and "http://ip-api.com/json/" but I have no idea how to use api for 100k of users, nor PHP or mysql code, or shell to do this.

I am using only PHP, MySQLi with MySQL database. The application will display a list of users "nearby" (within a 100miles radius).

Excuse me, I'm very new to programming and I really do not know how to solve this.

Edit:

I just created an api that returns me all user_id and their respective IPs in an array.
Just being 105k of records, for being json, it was light but I did not want to share json publicly here because it would be the same as explaining my users' data.
 
the result of api is something like this:

```
{
     "api_status": 200,
     "ips": [
         {
             "user_id": "1",
             "ip_address": "177.198.86.7x"
         },
         {
             "user_id": "21",
             "ip_address": "177.18.246.9x"
         },
         {
             "user_id": "52",
             "ip_address": "177.36.60.1x"
         }
     ]
}
```

I am using the following function to return my data in php

```
function List_ip() {
    global $sqlConnect, $db;
    if ($db['loggedin'] == false) {
        return false;
    }

    $ips = mysqli_query($sqlConnect, "SELECT `user_id` , `ip_address` FROM " . T_USERS . " WHERE `active` = '1'");
    while ($fetched_data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ips)) {
     $list_ip[] = array_map('utf8_encode', $fetched_data); 
    }    

   return $list_ip;

}
```

Comment: ip-api only allows  150 requests per minute from an IP address. If you go beyond that, your IP address will be blacklisted. To get the data, you can use PHP CURL

Comment: You will need to learn how to consume external APIs in php, there isn't much information in your question about what other frameworks you are using to display this data. for once off jobs like this, you can write a simple console or node application also.

Comment: Thanks for the support, I did not know this limitation.
So I would have to do a script with the limitation of requests per second right? Is there a sample of how to make cURL requests and impose a limit per second?

Comment: Adil H. Raza I'm not using frameworks. The application is developed in pure PHP, and is used as an application backend. The project uses only pure PHP, mysqli, and database mysql.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much idea about limiting the number of requests, but try the below code to get the details from ip-api.

```
    $url = "http://ip-api.com/batch";

$headers = array('Content-Type: application/json');

$fields = '[{"query": "208.80.152.201"}, // You can add multiple IP address in the same format.
  {"query": "8.8.8.8"},
  {"query": "24.48.0.1"}]';


$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
$httpCode = curl_getinfo($curl , CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); 
$response = curl_exec($curl);

if ($response === false) 
    $response = curl_error($curl);

  foreach(json_decode($response) as $value){


    echo $value->lat; //Use the result to store the information in DB
  }



curl_close($curl);
```

Refer their [documentation](http://ip-api.com/docs/api:batch) to get an idea about the data returned by their API.

Also, for limiting, try [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34475376/how-to-limit-the-number-of-user-requests-made-within-a-minute)

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for requires intermediate skills with PHP and MySQL etc.. I have done many things like this, and will tell you that firstly to get accurate GEO IP information you will have to use javascript or pay for a service (from my findings). For example www.maxmind.com has a free and pay, the pay is a bit better.

What I would do is try writing a script that reads all of the users out of the database in a loop, then download geopip or use an api to take the IP fields and return the Lat/Lon. Then finally add the step that writes it back to the DB .

A very rough example:

```
// build a class or function that looks up IP addresses (can be local)
$geoip2 = new GeoIp2Lookup(true);

// get all users from DB
$allUsersArray = function_results_db_lookup_users();

// get the users lat/lon
for ($i=0; $i<count($allUsersArray); $i++) {
  $record = $geoip2->getGeoDataArr($allUsersArray[$i]['ip_address']);
  $allUsersArray[$i]['lat'] = $record['lat'];
  $allUsersArray[$i]['lon'] = $record['lon'];
}

// now write a function to place in DB the new data
update_users_db($allUsersArray);
```

Comment: I understand that this needs skills that I do not have, so I went to this great platform. I would not imagine that my application would reach 100k users, even because I developed it with 1 month of PHP learning. I'm trying to study how this all works, but I really need help, because without the experience of better people than I, I will not get anywhere. Thanks for the comment

Comment: I updated the code with a rough view of how it would work as a command line script but I did not include the  code for how to interact with the DB or look up geo info using maxmind (which I have used in the past)..

Comment: That seems useful to me. I'll try. Thank you.

Comment: I am willing to help you if you wanted.... I would first create a php script you can run from command line that can perform  mysql SELECT * FROM users and put in a array and print.

Comment: Mike Q  I would greatly appreciate your help. I edited the question with more data. I did a function in PHP to get the data. How can I use the library you recommended to me now? Sorry to be so lazy, I've never worked with this before.

Answer (score 0):

The [maxmind/GeoIP2-php](https://github.com/maxmind/GeoIP2-php) should get you want you need.

Install it and download the [GeoIP2-City.mmdb](https://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/geolite2/) file.

Than just a matter of initiating it:

```
$record = new Reader('path/to/GeoLite2-City.mmdb');
```

and reading the data from it, such as:

```
$city = $record->city->name;
$latitude = $record->location->latitude;
$longitude = $record->location->longitude;
```

Doing it this way will mean zero dependency on third-party API limitations.

Comment: Hi, this will make me not have requests limitations per second? If so, I'll look at it for sure! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use the IP2Location PHP Module at https://www.ip2location.com/development-libraries/ip2location/php which is free.

To install, add the below line into your composer.json file.

```
{
  "require": {
    "ip2location/ip2location-php": "8.*"
  }
}
```

Run the command:

```
composer install
```

Note: You just need to include the below code in order to use the library.

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

You'll need the DB5.LITE database which you can download for free at https://lite.ip2location.com/

Example usage of the PHP module

```
<?php
require 'IP2Location.php';

$myip = '8.8.8.8';

$db = new \IP2Location\Database('./database/IP-COUNTRY-SAMPLE.BIN', \IP2Location\Database::FILE_IO);

$records = $db->lookup($myip, \IP2Location\Database::ALL);

echo '<pre>';
echo 'IP Address            : ' . $records['ipAddress'] . "\n";
echo 'Country Code          : ' . $records['countryCode'] . "\n";
echo 'Country Name          : ' . $records['countryName'] . "\n";
echo 'Region Name           : ' . $records['regionName'] . "\n";
echo 'City Name             : ' . $records['cityName'] . "\n";
echo 'Latitude              : ' . $records['latitude'] . "\n";
echo 'Longitude             : ' . $records['longitude'] . "\n";
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll certainly try that. But how will I use json to send all the IPs and get them back, or write them to the database?

Comment: The module accepts a single IP address. So you need to loop your array of IPs and query the IP2Location module for each IP. Then update your database with the result based on the IP address.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to study loops in PHP to try to solve this.
Anyway, do you suggest that I loop through a captured IP, and in that same loop I record the latitude and longitude in the database?
I think I understood your reasoning, I just do not know how to run it, but thanks.

Comment: Yes, as you query each IP and get the results, you need to update the database as well.