# How to set Rate Limiting from IP in PHP?

Tags: php, rate-limiting

I want to learn how can we set Rate Limiting through the IP.

Below is the scenario:-

Server --> 192.168.0.101
Client --> 192.168.0.29

Now, How can the server blocks the IP of the client if the client requests more than 50 times?

I have tried this code

```
<?php
session_start();

$remoteAdd = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."\n";

if (!isset($_SESSION['requests'])) {
    $_SESSION['requests'] = [];
}

$count = 0;
$requests = &$_SESSION['requests'];
echo "test";

foreach($requests as $request){


    echo $request["REMOTE_ADDR"];
    echo $remoteAdd;    
    if ($request["REMOTE_ADDR"] == $remoteAdd){

        echo "block";
    }
}
?>
```

This is what I understand (most probably I am wrong please correct me if), so it will make a list of requests in an array and then with the help of foreach it will find out the IP and match it with the target IP if it gets match it will block. But it didn't work.

Comment: SO is not the right place for asking for a tutorial (too broad and off-topic here). Better do a research on Google, make some attempts, and then come back here with your code and some debugging info if you'll face a specific problem. After 2 years of membership I would encourage you to read the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help)

Comment: Thank you @gp_sflover I always do some research before posting it. I was trying to find out on google but didn't get lucky. But yeah I found one thing which might give you a better view, I will EDIT this quest, please have a look after it.

Comment: This could be very complicated to achieve, but for sure it cannot be based only on client IP simply because it is so easy to spoof. Usually I would suggest a time-based (with or without a custom token/key generator) approach (per controller/action/or HTTP method). For a better research just use something like "http request rate limit" on google to start ;-)

Comment: Yeah, it can easily spoof, but I am working on a simple project where I need to do this. And I still didn't found any way to do it. So if you can please give me any hint or any suggestion that it would be very great. Additionally, the IP approach I didn't found anywhere.

Comment: you can start here https://stackoverflow.com/a/34475879/3695819 just search...